# convert stream object into string

Tags: node.js, stream, redis

i need to store a stream object as a string,
i tried to use `JSON.stringify(stream)` but i got the following error:

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
```

so i have tried to use "circular-json" package like this:

```
var o = CircularJSON.parse(CircularJSON.stringify(stream))
```

but when accessing the stream write function i get an error - 
`o.write is not a function`

how can i store stream objects as string, and parse them later
to the original object?

Comment: Streams usually have data that you have to read from using an event handler.  Where is this stream coming from?

Comment: Have you tried object mode option for reading stream?

Comment: tier1 - it is a stream from the package ssh2. simon-p-r - how can i use object mode to solve the problem?

Comment: Not sure if you can with ssh2 module, see this [article](https://nodesource.com/blog/understanding-object-streams/) which shows streams with object mode.

Answer (score 3):

Streams don't contain the raw data as part of the object. Instead they emit the data as part of `'data'` events that you can listen to. Subscribe to the `.on` event for the stream and when it emits data you can append it to a string and get all the data.

On the `'end'` event you have finished reading all the data so you can do something with the data in the `'end'` event callback.

```
let data = '';
stream.on('data', chunk => data += chunk);
stream.on('end', doSomethingWithData);
```

Comment: yes, but i need to store the actual stream, not the data. any idea how?

Comment: @markvolrap you can't store streams ... they are ephemeral. What do you mean by storing the stream?

Comment: i want to share the stream object across multiple servers, i am trying to do this with redis by making it a string then parse it back to an object.

Comment: @markvolrap you can't do that. What if the stream is trying to read from one filesystem? The severs probably don't share a filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

handling streams can be complicated. for `stream -> string`, i recommend using this library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/raw-body